# I need to generate a ppm signal using java that I can use to control my rc plane

Tags: java, generator

I am working on a program in java that will generate a ppm signal, using the computers audio card, that I can  use to control the servos on my rc plane. I want to be able to connect an audio cable to my laptop and to my rc transmitter, in trainer mode and start a program that will generate a ppm signal. I would like to generate at least 3 channels that I can use.

I have some code that I came up with while reading the java docs.

My problem is that I don't know how I can actually generate a ppm signal that I can use to control an rc plane with, using java.

For example the rc channels 1,2 and 3 can have the range of 0-2000 or 1000-2000, and the generated ppm signal would have the range of 0-100% (from my understanding).

Here's my code.

```
package java_PPM_test;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.sampled.SourceDataLine;


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new Main().go();
    }

    private void go(){
        float sampleRate=48000.0f;
        int sampleSizeInBits=16;
        int channels=1;
        int frameSize=2;
        float frameRate=48000.0f;
        boolean bigEndian=true;

        AudioFormat audio = new AudioFormat(AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED,sampleRate,sampleSizeInBits,channels,frameSize,frameRate,bigEndian);
        SourceDataLine output;

        try{
            output = AudioSystem.getSourceDataLine(audio);
            output.open();
            output.start();
            while(output.isRunning()){// this while never gets executed. I don't know why.
                byte[] myData={1};// I know that this byte array wont work for making a ppm signal, I just wanted to make sure the program would run.
                int off=0;
                int length=1;
                output.write(myData, off, length);// when I comment out the while, this statement generates an error
            }

        output.drain();
        output.stop();
        output.close();

        } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

}
```

I am thinking that all I have to do is figure out what kind of values to put in the byte array while the program is running.